# Jquery Increase div size on hover?

Tags: jquery, css

How to increase the div size on hover? Every div have the same class name, it's created dynamically. I tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.resultitem').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovers');
    $('.resultitem').not('.hover').css({ opacity: 0.3 });
});
$('.resultitem').bind('mouseout', function() {
    $('.resultitem').removeClass('hovers').fadeTo('normal',1);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.hovers {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
}
img.hovers {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
</style>
```

It changes the alignment of other div?

Comment: Please show your html too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use CSS3 `transform: scale(1.1)`

```css
.resultitem{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:#48e;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
          transition: 0.5s;
}

.resultitem:hover{
  background:#59f;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img class="resultitem" />
  <img class="resultitem" />
  <img class="resultitem" />
  <img class="resultitem" />
  <img class="resultitem" />
  <img class="resultitem" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this code that time hover div displayed  below to other div? i want that look like an google images?

Comment: @nagaking added a demo, take a look

Comment: http://goo.gl/Sd9Wz view this link on Internet Exlporer. If we move the cursor to the image means size of the image increased over other images.

Comment: @nagaking oh, missed that part, you can do it in pure CSS3

Comment: Its not work on Internet Explorer old version ..Is there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not using plain CSS?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/DkGtw/2/)

```
.sizeMe {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#F00;
    opacity:0.3;
    /* use 'opacity 1s ease' for just opacity */
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
.sizeMe:hover {
    height:400px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Because browsers don't support certain transitions (<=IE9).

Answer (score 1):

Try this
 jquery

```
$("#div1").hover(function () {
                $("#div1").addClass("divclass");
            }, function () {
                $("#div1").removeClass("divclass");
            });
```

html

```
           <div id="div1" >
            HTML borders are best created with CSS.
</div>
```

style

```
<style>
.divclass{width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid blue;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Css

```
add $(this).addClass('resize');

.resize:hover {
    width:Xpx;
    height:Ypx
}
```